# Need help with container sizes for planting herbs

Tags: containers, container-gardening

I'm a total noob when it comes to herb gardening and have a doubt here.

I've got 5 plastic containers, 4 small ones with about 7.5' diameter and 1 slightly larger at 10' diameter. The 5 herbs I want to plant are as follows:

1. Tulsi (Holy Basil)
2. Lemon Grass
3. Sage
4. Curry Leaves
5. Pudina (Peppermint)

It might sound odd but I want to make the most optimum/efficient use of the planting containers, so I want to know which one of these 5 herbs require the maximum space or container width? That way I shall use the larger 10' container for that one herb and smaller 7.5' for others.

Comment: Either the Lemongrass or the Curry leaf plant in the larger pot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curry leaf is my vote for the larger pot. The plant grows into a tree with enough space, and you don't want to restrict growth.

Lemongrass will do better in the larger pot, but it'll do just fine in the smaller one.

Basil isn't picky--it grows to match the container space available. Sage and mint will do fine in a smaller pot. If they're properly fertilized, they sprawl out and use up all the soil space available.